# Witdh div in div use 100% and have padding

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am wanting to put a div inside another, and within that div has a padding of 10px, and this is div width to 100%. But to do this, the div goes outside the parent div.

Example here in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kCypn/5/

```
.caixa
{   
    float : left;
    width:100%;    
    background-color:white;
    padding:25px;
}
```

Another problem I have, I have a div aligned left with width of 150px and another div to occupy all the remaining space and padding.

Comment: Just use the `box-sizing: border-box` for the `.caixa` div. Of course to make it cross-browser u need to use prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

By default CSS box model calculates the final width of the element as a sum of its `width`, `border` and `padding`. You can overcome this confusing behaviour by using `box-sizing` property:

```
.caixa
{   
    float : left;
    width:100%;    
    background-color:white;
    padding:25px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCypn/7/

Read about it: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ 
Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 0):

`width + padding = Total value` So it is causing scroll bar. Remove `float` and `width` from `.caixa`

```
.caixa
{     
    background-color:white;
    padding:25px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kCypn/6/)**

Comment: Tks...
And the other situation I want to have a div fixed to left with a value X and the other div to occupy all the space that remains, so that the second div has dynamic width and the first div is always fixed.

Answer (score 0):

now **remove** `float` or `width 100%` in your `.caixa` **class** because **div is** allready `width 100%;` and now define `padding` as you wish

```
.caixa{   
    float : left; // remove this line
    width:100%; // remove this line

}
```

**[Demo Full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/kCypn/8/embedded/result/)**

**[Demo in window](http://jsfiddle.net/kCypn/8/)**

I check to your code **they are not required** `float left` or `width 100%` in your **class** `.caixa`